# Center text in table cell

Tags: html, html-table, alignment, center

I can't seem to find the answer to my issue. I have a table with two rows and two columns (like the code shown below), how do I center align the text in specific cells. I would like to center align the text in one or two of the cells - not all the cells.

```html
<div style="text-align: center;">
    <table style="margin: 0px auto;" border="0">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Cell 1</td>
                <td>Cell 2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cell 3</td>
                <td>Cell 4</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 58, accepted):

I would recommend using CSS for this. You should create a CSS rule to enforce the centering, for example:

```
.ui-helper-center {
    text-align: center;
}
```

And then add the `ui-helper-center` class to the table cells for which you wish to control the alignment:

```
<td class="ui-helper-center">Content</td>
```

---

**EDIT**: Since this answer was accepted, I felt obligated to edit out the parts that caused a flame-war in the comments, and to not promote poor and outdated practices.

See [Gabe's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7641130/center-text-in-table-cell/7641141#7641141) for how to include the CSS rule into your page.

Comment: CSS 1 became a recommendation almost 15 years ago. Don't use the align attribute.

Comment: @Quentin - Agreed about "don't use 'align'".  But Cory Larson himself recommended the CSS equivalent over "align=center".  I hope you don't mark him down (and if you did, please consider changing it. OK?)

Comment: @paulsm4 — I didn't, and he hadn't when I made the comment.

Comment: Thank you for all your suggestions. I know very little about css. Where should I place the CSS rule in my code?

Comment: @Jack - in the header section of your html document.  Ideally, you'd want to create a css include file and link it from the header:  http://htmlhelp.com/reference/css/style-html.html

Answer (score 6):

How about simply (Please note, come up with a better name for the class name this is simply an example):

```
.centerText{
   text-align: center;
}


<div>
   <table style="width:100%">
   <tbody>
   <tr>
      <td class="centerText">Cell 1</td>
      <td>Cell 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="centerText">Cell 3</td>
      <td>Cell 4</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gmcalab/w2kJK/4/)

You can place the `css` in a separate file, which is recommended.
In my example, I created a file called `styles.css` and placed my `css` rules in it.
Then include it in the html document in the `<head>` section as follows:

```
<head>
    <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
```

The alternative, not creating a seperate css file, not recommended at all...
Create `<style>` block in your `<head>` in the html document. Then just place your rules there.

```
<head>
 <style type="text/css">
   .centerText{
       text-align: center;
    }
 </style>
</head>
```