# How to center the content of a <td> in a Datatable

Tags: html, css, datatables

I have a datatable with a css square inside a `<td>` that I want to center but I don't know how can I do it.

Image of the misaligned square:

[image]

What I've tried so far:

`th.dt-center, td.dt-center { text-align: center; }`

`columnDefs: [ { className: 'text-center', targets: '_all' }, ]`

Based on what I saw in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45446910/jquery-datatables-align-center-1-column)

I also tried:

```
<th style="text-align:center;"></th>
<td style="text-align:center;"></td>
```

And it worked for `<th>` but not for `<td>`

And also I tried the solution [provided here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46832709/datatables-align-center)

```
"columnDefs": [
    {"className": "dt-center", "targets": "_all"}
]
```

So far I have not managed to center the square in any way

[LIVE DEMO JS BIN](http://live.datatables.net/vepedopa/24/edit?output)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Center text in table cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7641130/center-text-in-table-cell)

Comment: the square element (`.square`) behaves like a block, so using inline or text style rules like `text-center` won't produce the behaviour you expect.
To center a block level element, declare `margin: auto` on the block element itself, i.e. `.square { margin: auto; }`

Comment: @blurfus No it didn’t

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add a [mcve] for faster troubleshooting.  There is no particular reason why the answer above should have not worked for you so it must be something very specific to your code and since we cannot see it, we'd be guessing at an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`margin: 0 auto;` should work on the `.square` class.

Answer (score 0):

from what I understand from your question, just simply use

```
td {
     text-align:center;
}
```

And if you want for square also to center then,

```
th,td {
     text-align:center;
}
```

Also shared the link here for the changes [live link](http://live.datatables.net/vepedopa/28/edit),

Answer (score 0):

Try using flexbox to your table column.

```
td {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).